# Create custom graphic in CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to somehow create the following in CSS? (See attached image)

[image]

What i want to achieve is to be able to change the background-color of the bubble with CSS.

One solution would be to save the background bubble in a bunch of different colors and depending on the color chosen display the correct background image. However this would not be as dynamic as i wish.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this was done over at CSS Tricks using pseudo-elements.  The only limitation I can think of or foresee is the border that goes around the object...  [CSS Round-out borders](http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/)

Using the :after and :before pseudo elements I was able to take the same concept and apply it to create your shape. Again...  The only catch is the border.  Also... it requires the background behind it to be solid, so that you can mimic the background color...  No patterns or transparency here.  Try changing the colors of the :after and :before elements and you'll see how its done.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5HBpc/)

```
<div class="bubble">
    <span>Some Text</span>
</div>

body { background: #999;}

.bubble {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #444;
}

.bubble:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -30px;
    background: #444;
}

.bubble:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -60px;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other options are nice css approaches but with the border on a shape like that will not be possible with just css.

In my approach I am going to use an `svg` image.

This is a path in the image and as you can see classes and ids are possible to use on an `svg` image.

```
<path class="bubBg" fill="#7C7C7C"
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbj8b/1/) you can play around with.

(currently I believe this is the best option to have that *exact* design but Michael's answer is pretty good)

Comment: Sadly only 9 and up, http://caniuse.com/svg. Any of these options that are posted is about the same I believe. Pseudo(:before/:after) is only partial support on IE8 and none below, http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did: Not exactly the same bubble but similiar, Check it out

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zD3bV/1/

**CSS**

```
#speech-bubble {
  width: 120px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background: purple;
   top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#speech-bubble:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 26px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  margin: 13px 0 0 -25px;
}
 #talk-bubble {
    width:120px;
    height:80px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
  #talk-bubble:before {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        right:100%;
        top:26px;
        width:0;
         height:0;
        border-top:13px solid transparent;
         border-right:26px solid blue;
        border-bottom:13px solid transparent;
   }
```

Also, search for css shapes you'll more likely to get the best results and then you can modify them according to your needs